# Facebook Javascript SDK FB.getLoginStatus returns null session even when the user is connected

Tags: javascript, facebook, session

I use this code to check if a user has an open Facebook session and has allowed my app:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {

   FB.init({
          appId   : 'MY APP ID',
          status  : true, // check login status
          cookie  : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
          xfbml   : true // parse XFBML
        });

function checkLoginFB() { 
  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {        
     if (response.session) {
       // logged in and connected user, someone you know
       showLogout();
      } else {
       // no user session available, someone you dont know
       showLogin();
      }
  });
 }

(function() {
        var e = document.createElement('script');
        e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        e.async = true;
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
      }());

}
```

But no matter what (whether the user is signed in to Facebook AND has allowed my application or not)
I get a null value for response.session. does anyone know why?

Comment: just to verify you are in fact changing the `'MY APP ID'` to reflect your actual app id correct?

Comment: Yes, I just used 'MY APP ID' for this post.

Comment: Where is this happening? On the live site or in a dev environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here was caused by my having "accept 3rd party cookies' turned off in my browser.
I had not even thought about this since I didn't even remember turning them off.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the SDK is not loading correctly. If you `console.log` FB var, what do you get?

Check that you have a div with id `fb-root` into your HTML and it's placed **before** the JS that you have posted.